# Why does non-const shared_ptr ref not work polymorphically?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

If I want to use `shared_ptr` polymorphically, why is `std::shared_ptr<A>& ptr` not working? However, `const std::shared_ptr<A>& ptr` works fine.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "B " << std::endl; }
};

void working(const std::shared_ptr<A>& ptr) {
    ptr->foo();
}

void not_working(std::shared_ptr<A>& ptr) {
    ptr->foo();
}

int main() {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<B>();
    working(ptr);

    not_working(ptr); // <-- compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling, I get the following compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:44:16: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr<A>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::shared_ptr<A>’
   44 |     notworking(ptr);
      |                ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/memory:77,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr.h:296:9: note:   after user-defined conversion: ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<_Yp>&) [with _Yp = B; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = A]’
  296 |         shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Yp>& __r) noexcept
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:37: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void notworking(std::shared_ptr<A>&)’
   32 | void notworking(std::shared_ptr<A>& ptr) {
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
make: *** [<builtin>: main] Error 1
```

Comment: The `not_working` has to make a **temporary**, which isn't allowed to be bound to a non-const parameter reference.

Comment: Always include the error when making a post. Your question makes it sound like `A::foo` was called, but this is actually a compilation error.

Comment: It's because types are unrelated, but there is a conversion from `shared_ptr<B>` to `shared_ptr<A>`, and a const reference can bind to the temporary result of that conversion. That is, the working version does not pass a reference to `ptr` but to a new, temporary, object. (There is almost never any point to passing the "smart pointers" by reference.)

Comment: *"If I want to use shared_ptr polymorphic"* -- Do you mean "use polymorphism via a `shared_ptr`"? (If so, one might ask why it's important that `shared_ptr` be used -- is `not_working()` supposed to change the pointer, as opposed to the pointed-to object?)

Comment: The same thing happens with raw pointers: https://godbolt.org/z/TvzMzT6s4

Comment: thx... this explains it. @molbdnilo If remember correctly, I read in Scott Meyers book, that even shared_ptr should be passed by reference. For example to avoid the inc/dec of the reference counter which is atomic and thus a little more time consuming than normal inc/dec.

Comment: @antibus *"to avoid the inc/dec of the reference counter"* -- passing the object by reference (`A&`) also avoids changing the reference count, plus it does not lock callers into having shared pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>` are distinct and unrelated types.  `B` deriving from `A` does not make `shared_ptr<B>` derive from `shared_ptr<A>`.

Since `B` derives from `A`, there is an implicit conversion from `B*` to `A*`, and so the compiler is allowed to assign a `shared_ptr<B>` object to a `shared_ptr<A>` object, and they will both be pointing at the same `B` object.

When calling `working()`, the compiler has to create a temporary `shared_ptr<A>` object from the `shared_ptr<B>` object. And since a const reference can bind to a temporary, this works as expected.

When calling `not_working()`, the compiler still has to create a temporary `shared_ptr<A>` object. But, since a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary, you get the error.

Answer (score 3):

In one you implicitly convert `shared_ptr<B>` to `shared_ptr<A>`. In the other one you try to pass by non-const reference.

It similar to `foo(const int&)` accepting a `double` as input while `foo(int&)` wouldn't.

If you erase `&` it will fix the error.